# Saída sempre a mesma em C

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber porque o último `printf` do meu programa é sempre o mesmo? Fiz ele em C e sou iniciante. O objetivo do programa é verificar se um número
é palíndromo ou não. Mas quando chega a hora de imprimir o resultado, em todas as execuções do programa o resultado é sempre que o número não é palíndromo. Como resolvo isso?

### Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
     char *p1, *p2;

  if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;
  for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
  {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
  }
  return str;
}

char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";
    char* p = b;
    if(i<0){
        *p++ = '-';
        i *= -1;
    }
    int shifter = i;
    do{ //Move to where representation ends
        ++p;
    shifter = shifter/10;
    }while(shifter);
    *p = '\0';
    do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
        *--p = digit[i%10];
        i = i/10;
    }while(i);

}

int main(void){
    int contaDigit = 0, valor;
    int numberWantToCheck;
    printf("What's the number you want to check?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numberWantToCheck);
    valor = numberWantToCheck;
    do{
         contaDigit += 1;
         valor /= 10;
    }while(valor != 0);
    char stringOfTheNum[contaDigit];
    itoa(numberWantToCheck, stringOfTheNum);
    char reversedNum[contaDigit];
    strcpy(reversedNum, strrev(stringOfTheNum));
    if(strcmp(reversedNum , stringOfTheNum)){
        printf("The number is palindrome.\n");
    }else{
        printf("The number is not palindrome.\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há dois problemas principais com o código acima.

1. A sua implementação de `strrev` simultaneamente inverte a String recebida como parâmetro *in-place* e retorna um ponteiro para essa String.

   Dessa forma a linha `strcpy(reversedNum, strrev(stringOfTheNum));` não faz exatamente o que você espera. `stringOfTheNum` é invertida primeiro e depois copiada para `reversedNum`. O resultado é que `stringOfTheNum` sempre será igual a `reversedNum` (ambas invertidas). Você pode contornar esse problema copiando a String primeiro e invertendo depois:

   ```
   char stringOfTheNum[contaDigit];
   char reversedNum[contaDigit];
   itoa(numberWantToCheck, stringOfTheNum); // converte o numero original para String
   strcpy(reversedNum, stringOfTheNum); // copia a string para reversedNum
   strrev(reversedNum); // inverte reversedNum
   ```
2. O segundo problema é que `strcmp` retorna `0` quando duas Strings são iguais. Em C `0` é equivalente a `false`, logo, sua condição está invertida. O correto seria:

   ```
   if(strcmp(reversedNum , stringOfTheNum) == 0) {
       printf("The number is palindrome.\n");
   } else {
       printf("The number is not palindrome.\n");
   }
   ```

   Ou ainda:

   ```
   if(strcmp(reversedNum , stringOfTheNum)) {
       printf("The number is not palindrome.\n");
   } else {
      printf("The number is palindrome.\n");
   }
   ```

[**Veja Funcionando no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/5MCd7n)

---

Há outras melhorias possíveis no código.

Um dos problemas, ao meu ver, é que você está reimplementando funções não padronizadas no C como `itoa` e `strrev` ao invés de se valer de funções da biblioteca padrão.

Alguns exemplos:

1. Toda a parte do código que computa a quantidade de caracteres necessários para o buffer pode ser substituída por:

   ```
   int bufferSize = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", numberWantToCheck) + 1;
   // O +1 está prevendo que a linha será terminada em NUL ('\0')
   ```

   Porém, `bufferSize` não é nem mesmo necessário; basta usar um buffer de tamanho fixo grande o suficiente para conter o valor máximo de dígitos que um inteiro pode ter na sua plataforma + dois caracteres extras; um para um possível sinal negativo + um para o terminador de strings. Por exemplo: para inteiros de 32 bits o valor máximo de um inteiro seria +2,147,483,647 (10 dígitos), assim, seu programa pode armazenar todos os valores de entrada possíveis usando Strings de tamanho igual a 12. Como memória não é um recurso assim tão escasso para a grande maioria dos sistemas, você poderia inclusive usar uma buffer grosseiramente superestimado (e.g., `char[100]`) e não se preocupar com o assunto.
2. A função `itoa` no seu caso também pode ser substituída por:

   ```
   snprintf(stringOfTheNum, bufferSize, "%d", numberWantToCheck);
   ```
3. A implementação de `strrev` acima (encontrada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534275/664577)) é muito inteligente, porém usa truques envolvendo aritmética de ponteiros + operações de XOR que claramente não são o trabalho de um iniciante. Na verdade, esse é o tipo de código "esperto", difícil de ler, que eu substituiria por um loop trivial + variável temporária em 99.9% dos casos. O compilador faz um trabalho muito bom otimizando esse tipo de coisa; não digo que esse é necessariamente o caso desse código, porém já encontrei muitas "otimizações" como essa que acabam piorando a performance da aplicação. Se algum aluno meu me entregasse uma função assim como parte de um exercício eu muito provavelmente pediria para ele me explicar como esse código funciona, bem como a motivação para tal "otimização".

Finalmente, como sua entrada sempre é um número, você não precisaria nem mesmo converter seu inteiro para uma String, veja [esse exemplo](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/palindrome-number). Sem usar *arrays* de caracteres o código em questão fica bem mais simples. E de quebra você não precisa se preocupar com *buffer overflow* e demais problemas desse gênero.